# Trace out a pygame circle animation

Tags: python, pygame, geometry

I have been googling around for the answer to this but I'm not sure how to phrase the keywords to get what I'm looking for. What I want to do is animate a pygame circle. Not just move it in x or y direction, but animate the drawing of it, like I'm tracing it. It would be much like [this gif](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/mathematical/cardioid_animation_2.gif), if all you saw was the red part on screen as it was being drawn, and the shape of the red part was a circle. The circle will have to do this animation multiple times (it is signaling the reloading of a gun) so it would have to reset itself and redraw the animation whenever the user presses "r". The circle is in one stationary place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use a sprite animation or maybe blit several images one after each other to create a small animation

try this:

https://github.com/ankur0890/Pygame-Examples-For-Learning/blob/master/fireSprite.png?raw=true

if you take that image and run this code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

counter=0
def Update():
 global counter
 counter=(counter+1)%7

def sprite(w, h):
    a=[]
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((200,200),0,24)
    image = pygame.image.load("fireSprite.png").convert_alpha()
    width,height=image.get_size()
    for i in xrange(int(width/w)):
        a.append(image.subsurface((i*w,0,w,h)))
    while True:
        for i in pygame.event.get():
            if i.type==QUIT:
                exit()
        screen.fill((0,0,0)) 
        screen.blit(a[counter],(100,100))
        Update()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(5)

   sprite(20,20)
```

this code will play the image i linked in an animation

here is the image [fireSprite.png](https://github.com/ankur0890/Pygame-Examples-For-Learning/blob/master/fireSprite.png?raw=true)

Comment: I explored this idea as well but I still don't fully understand how this code works and i was hoping for a shorter, easier solution.

Comment: yeah it is kind of long its just hard to get a small animation into pygame like that i cant really think of any other ways that are easier ill look around!!

Answer (score 1):

Draw an [arc](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc), animating the start/stop angle (e.g. set the start angle to *0* and animate the stop angle from *0* to *2π*).

> *[pygame.draw.arc()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc)*
>
> draw a partial section of an ellipse

```
arc(Surface, color, Rect, start_angle, stop_angle, width=1) -> Rect
```

> Draws an elliptical arc on the Surface. The rect argument is the area that the ellipse will fill. The two angle arguments are the initial and final angle in radians, with the zero on the right. The width argument is the thickness to draw the outer edge.

Comment: i guess that makes sense the issue is that I have to make this circle thicker than 1px and the default pygame width setting is not quality, if you get my gist.

Comment: Use a sprite then (Christian's answer).